# Dynamically create databases with php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I new with php.
I want to dynamically create data bases.  I found that Doctrine 2 ORM can create db from command line. But i have some questions:
1. Its possible do it not in command line but in php code? Cant find any examples.
2. If i have a db connection configuration in bootstrap.php, how can i create db dynamically?
Maybe exists better way to do it, but i watch in Doctrine tutorial and its do much good things that i want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create database in PostgreSQL using following code

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname
```

Below is the basic **syntax** of creating database in PostgreSQL...

```
CREATE DATABASE name
    [ [ WITH ] [ OWNER [=] user_name ]
           [ TEMPLATE [=] template ]
           [ ENCODING [=] encoding ]
           [ LC_COLLATE [=] lc_collate ]
           [ LC_CTYPE [=] lc_ctype ]
           [ TABLESPACE [=] tablespace ]
           [ CONNECTION LIMIT [=] connlimit ] ]
```

Read [PostgreSQL: Create Database manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html) for more information

Comment: So it's mean that i cant create data base with Doctrine?

Comment: you can create database using PHP..

Comment: Yeah it's right. I just want to find correct way to do it. Becouse if i use Doctrine to work with data base, i think it's will nice if only Doctrine will work with data base.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The only thing required is that your db account used in php **has the privilege of creating database**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the database user you are using has table creation privileges it should be just a matter of submitting the appropriate SQL query. I have used PHP to create a log table which wrote to a new database each day to reduce insert times and allow easy archiving of old logs.

mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

...

ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");

Answer (score 0):

This php code will create a database named temp on localhost. The user should have the privileges to create databases.
Replace  with your db username and  with your db password.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",<user>,<password>);

$sql="CREATE DATABASE temp";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  echo "Database created successfully";
}
else
{
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```